# VSTO C# Word InlineShape add Link

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

BreakLink() breaks the link between an InlineShape and the source file.
Is it possible to add a link to an existing InlineShape in a Word document?

Comment: If you mean "turn an inlineshape with no link into an inlineshape linked to a file", the main question is "do you know where the file is"? If you do, you would probably delete the image Andre-insert. If you don't, the answer is "no". Or maybe you meant something else?

Comment: This is what I want to do. Actually the link path is saved in the images title. Therefore, I can break the link and give the document to somebody without the source files available. When the user press F9 not all images disappear. On the other hand for editing the file I will restore the links. I can do as proposed: delete image and insert a linked image again.

Comment: If you mean the picture full name (path+name) is in activedocument.inlineshapes(x).Title for shape no. x,  it should be straightforward, except you may have to save the picture's property values and restore them after re-insertion. In essence in VBA you might do Set shp = Activedocument.Inlineshapes(x) pathname = shp.Title Set rng = shp.Range shp.Delete Set shp = rng..InlineShapes.AddPicture(fullname, True) . OTOH if you mean the fullname is in a caption somewhere nearby, a bit more work needed!

Comment: Of course the path isn't stored in the title by default. I am working with an Add-In storing the path in the title, or break the link. The next feature will be restoring links.